# Javascript não funciona em Webview

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho este motor de busca simples, funciona em todos os navegadores, mesmo no chrome do android, mas não funciona em Webviews, alguma sugestão do que possa ser e se há algum outro código compatível que possa substituir este,Tem como fazer isso sem ser por javascript, usando `target` e `action` por exemplo, e como habilitar isso para webview??

```html
<form align="center" method="GET">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Digite Sua Pergunta Aqui" autofocus name="query" size="50">
        <input  type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Buscar">
    </form>
        
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var query = document.getElementsByName('query')[0];
      window.open("endereco_site" + query.value);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Você está habilitando o uso de JavaScript no WebView?

Comment: Qual o comportamento que espera? quer dizer, onde essa janela vai abrir? vai sair do app e ir para o navegador?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr no caso é o usuário que vai ter que habilitar isso?

Comment: @MiguelSilva Não, é o desenvolvedor. Para o JavaScript funcionar, é necessário o desenvolvedor atribuir o valor `true` no método `webView.setJavaScriptEnabled` (no caso do Android). E como você está usando `popup`, talvez haja seja por isso também (não cheguei a testar algo do tipo).

Comment: @DavidSchrammel é um app que abre uma página usando webview, quando o usuário digita a pergunta e clica em buscar ele abre outra página com o resultado da busca, só que webview ao invés de aparecer o campo de texto e o submit aparecem dois campos seguido do código java script assim:    
`function myFunction() {
      var query = document.getElementsByName('query')[0];
      window.open("endereco_site" + query.value);
    }`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr entendi

Comment: Tem como fazer isso sem ser por javascript?

Comment: @MiguelSilva Utilizando *modal*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que para ativar o Javascript tenha que definir o `WebChromeClient`:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

E depois habilitar o JavaScript

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Exemplo:

```
package foo.bar.baz; //nome do seu pacote, isso é apenas um exemplo

import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView meuWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        meuWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); //Busca o seu webView (se estiver layout)
        meuWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        meuWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    }
}
```

---

Como adicional, você perguntou:

> Tem como fazer isso sem ser por javascript?

Tem sim, usando o `target=` e `action=` no form, por exemplo:

```
<form action="http://endereço" align="center" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Digite Sua Pergunta Aqui" autofocus name="query" size="50">
    <input  type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Comment: Muito Show, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: se eu usar um target="_blank" vai funcionar em webviews? ou terei problemas? me refiro a opção apenas com action e target

Comment: @MiguelSilva ah verdade, creio que não, eu vou me retratar e melhorar a pergunta, acho que para ambos casos será necessário implementar algo a mais. Vou testar e assim que possivel já retorno.

Comment: Testei e funcionou usando o `target`  e `action`, assim não precisa fazer alteração no APP. Obrigado.

Comment: @MiguelSilva então tem que usar o `onCreateWindow` eu estou preparando um exemplo, eu não consegui criar um ainda (é que eu procuro sempre testar meus exemplos antes de postar) porque algumas coisas mudaram no meu trabalho e estou sobrecarregado :(